# Data from vault with with_items groups

Tags: ansible

I have a task that generates my configuration from jinja2 to conf.

```
- name: check password
  set_fact:
    my_secrets: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=kv/{{ stage }}.d/{{ app }}/{{ item }}/secrets token={{ token }} url={{ url }} validate_certs={{ validate_certs }}')}}"
  with_items: "{{ groups['ns'] }}"
```

```
- name: copy config powerdns_auth pdns.local.gmysql.conf
  template:
    src: ../../../update/ns/templates/etc/powerdns/pdns.d/pdns.local.gmysql.conf.j2
    dest: ../../../config/{{ stage }}/{{ item }}/etc/powerdns/pdns.d/pdns.local.gmysql.conf
    mode: '0644'
  with_items: "{{ groups['ns'] }}"
```

in pdns.local.gmysql.conf.j2

```
gmysql-password={{ my_secrets.user_password_mysql }}
```

I have a problem because it saves me the from vault password from the last host to a file.

Is it possible to set the fact depending on the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't loop over groups, use the "natural" play loop on hosts and delegate the needed tasks to localhost.

Note: I kept your relative paths in the template tasks but it looks ugly and will break one day or an other.

Note2: "[moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)" => I fixed your code (there are other ways to fix it...) where it was incorrect when fetching from hashicorp vault.

```yaml
- name: Create config files per hosts
  hosts: ns
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # All your needed vars that I will not define here for this example

  tasks:
    - name: check password
      vars:
        secret: "kv/{{ stage }}.d/{{ app }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/secrets"
        hashi_string: "secret={{ secret }} token={{ token }} url={{ url }} validate_certs={{ validate_certs }}"
      set_fact:
        my_secrets: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', hashi_string) }}"

    - name: copy config powerdns_auth pdns.local.gmysql.conf
      template:
        src: ../../../update/ns/templates/etc/powerdns/pdns.d/pdns.local.gmysql.conf.j2
        dest: ../../../config/{{ stage }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/powerdns/pdns.d/pdns.local.gmysql.conf
        mode: '0644'
      delegate_to: localhost
```